# How do I make entity reference lookup faster

Tags: 8, entities

I am trying to look up entity reference id's for each node so I can do stuff with them.

```
$all_nodes = db_select('node','e')->fields('e',array('nid','type'));
$all_nodes->addField('e','nid');
$all_nodes->condition('type','author');
$data = $all_nodes->execute();
$the_result = $data->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

foreach ($the_result as $node){
     $node_load =  \Drupal\node\Entity\Node::load($node['nid']);
     foreach ($node_load->field_institution_with_date as $item) {
        $the_entity_id = $item->entity->id();
     }
}
```

Any idea on how to optimize this? it seems that `$item->entity->id();` is the bottleneck and it is taking several seconds to iterate through about 1000 nodes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ideally you'd use an [Entity Query](https://docs.acquia.com/article/lesson-61-entity-queries-and-loading-entities) for this, but in principle:

1. You can batch load the parent nodes

   ```
   ...
   $nids = $data->fetchCol();

   foreach (Node::loadMultiple($nids) as $node) {
   ```

   If memory is a concern with thousands of nodes, just implement some simple php logic around the loop to batch it into, say, 50-100 at a time.
2. If you don't need the child entities, just their IDs, they're available without a DB hit

   ```
   foreach ($node_load->field_institution_with_date as $item) {
       $the_entity_id = $item->target_id;
   ```

   If you do need the entities, you could build an array of all IDs using this method, and batch load those using `Node::loadMultiple` after the outer loop.

Comment: Thanks, option 2 worked great. It reduced the time by a lot (shaved about 4 seconds off total execution time). I am not quite sure what you mean by batch loading but I will try that out too. Thanks again!

Comment: I tried out option 1, and didn't see much of a performance gain there really. The speed is mainly dependent on how many nodes I go through and load up. Can I load them up concurrently somehow?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean by concurrently exactly?